# Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined

Tags: javascript, ajax

i have a "a href" tag and when on click this, calling a function but this not working and i receive an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Gonder is not defined index.php:10
onclick
```

javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){
    function Gonder(nereden, nereye) {

       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ara.php",
            data: '{ "nereden":"' + nereden + '", "nereye":"' + nereye + '" }',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (result) {              
                $("#sonuc").html(result.d);

            },
            error: function (result) {

                $("#sonuc").html(result.d);


            }
        });
    }

});




</script>
```

html code :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="Gonder(100, 101);" title="">
click</a>
```

not working...

Comment: `Gonder` is not in scope. You should add the event _in JavaScript_. See here http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Why you placed a semi colon Gonder(100, 101); at last? remove that

Comment: it is a href onclick function parameters

Comment: define the functio outside document ready ... just try

Comment: post a fiddle that will help us to check

Comment: tried, don't error but now anything happened. not posted parameters to php

Comment: try the data mentioned by @piwolli so your function get called now?

Comment: Define the function in the head tag without a ready event. Your function will be defined at the moment the onclick calls it.

Comment: i tried it but not worked :(

Comment: Post a fiddle that will be great... Is your function get called atleast?

Comment: It does work: http://jsfiddle.net/4mEhG/

Comment: alert working but ajax code not working

Comment: That's a whole different problem. You function undefined is working now. Open developer tools with `F12`(Chrome) and check if you get any errors. At least your `data` is wrong. This has te be a JS object like `data : {myKey : 'key', myKey2 : 'key2'}`

Comment: chrome: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: Gonder is not defined index.php:10
onclick'

Answer (score 0):

Function is not defined -error might happend when the function is defined incorrectly / has bugs in it.

In your case this at least is wrong:

```
data: '{ "nereden":"' + nereden + '", "nereye":"' + nereye + '" }',
```

And should be:

```
data: { nereden: nereden, nereye: nereye },
```

Answer (score 0):

As comment posted above by me,

I hope defining the function outside the document ready will help and make use the function.
so **define that function out of document ready** as like below,
and i hope data format need to change as you asked the data not sending to php code use the Piwolli data format instead your's.

```
function Gonder(nereden, nereye) {

   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ara.php",
        data: '{ "nereden":"' + nereden + '", "nereye":"' + nereye + '" }',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (result) {              
            $("#sonuc").html(result.d);

        },
        error: function (result) {

            $("#sonuc").html(result.d);


        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Ha ha ha if you think if code not working we have to break pc there will be no pc in this world...

Comment: @GuyT you tellin gto me? or user3800622

Comment: @AntoKing I'm giving that advice to user3800622 ofcourse ;)

Comment: thanks for everything, if i solve this problem , i will write to you. good days :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/z8n68/

HTML

```
<a id="test" href="javascript:void(0);" title="">click</a>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#test").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    Gonder(100,101);
});

function Gonder(nereden, nereye) {

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ara.php",
    data: '{ "nereden":"' + nereden + '", "nereye":"' + nereye + '" }',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (result) {              
        $("#sonuc").html(result.d);

    },
    error: function (result) {

        $("#sonuc").html(result.d);


    }
  });
  }
});
```